# Remove a line in character vector in R

Tags: r

I have a character vector as follows

```
<spec>
<h5><hdtitle>Tighten</hdtitle></h5>
Tighten the bolts to 10N m
(89lbin).
</spec>
```

I want to remove line 2 `<h5><hdtitle>Tighten</hdtitle></h5>` based on the condition that Tighten occurs in consecutive lines.

Required Output

```
<spec>
Tighten the bolts to 10N m
(89lbin).
</spec>
```

Comment: That doesn't really look like a character vector would.  Can you add the output from `dput()` on the example please.

Answer (score 2):

Since your example looks more like part of an HTML document than it does a character vector, I would recommend trying the XML package.  Its `removeNodes()` function makes this task quite simple.

```
x <- '<spec>
<h5><hdtitle>Tighten</hdtitle></h5>
Tighten the bolts to 10N m
(89lbin).
</spec>'

library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(x)
removeNodes(list(doc["//h5"][[1]]))
# NULL
```

And then we have

```
doc["//spec"][[1]]
# <spec>
# Tighten the bolts to 10N m
# (89lbin).
# </spec>
```

And you can base this on whether "Tighten" occurs on both lines with something like

```
doc <- htmlParse(x)
s <- stringi::stri_count_fixed(xmlValue(doc["//spec"][[1]]), "Tighten")
if(s > 1) {
    removeNodes(list(doc["//h5"][[1]]))
}
doc["//spec"][[1]]
# <spec>
# Tighten the bolts to 10N m
# (89lbin).
# </spec>
```